# Gradient (Perlin) noise and value noise comparison

Tags: reference-request, noise, random-functions

This question is referenced to [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184121/why-is-gradient-noise-better-quality-than-value-noise)
and i am terribly sorry to ask it like this, but i have not enough reputation to add a comment, therefore i can't ask my question there. So does anyone know some official studies or articles explaining why gradient noise is better? I have read linked question (there is only one source link and it is broken), but i need a reference for my assignment and probably more details. A couple of weeks ago i have seen one, but unfortunately i can't find it anymore.

Please, if anyone knows something - leave link in the comment and i will delete this question.

Comment: The answers in your linked question give the clues. You don't like them ?

Comment: @user1952009 I have googled this question for a couple of hours and, yes,  i understand why gradient is better, however i  want to find a good article as a reference to put in my assignment. By the way, i have seen one but can't find it. That is my request.